# rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: Permiso denegado

Tags: fedora

Hello need help with this error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm --addsign php-composer-ca-bundle-1.0.2-1.fc22.remi.noarc
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: No existe el fichero o el directorio
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir /usr/bin/rpmsign
rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: Permiso denegado
```

System is Fedora 22
no internet conection to solve via yum install

Comment: Please run these commands with `LANG=C` prepended (assuming you're using Bash or zsh). That way you'll get error messages in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error message which says that the file `/usr/bin/rpmsign` doesn't exist:

> ```
> rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: No existe el fichero o el directorio
> ```

(In English, that would be `rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: No such file or directory`.)

You respond to that by just *creating* the missing thing as a directory with `mkdir`:

> ```
> [root@localhost ~]# mkdir /usr/bin/rpmsign
> ```

I guess that follows a certain logic, but the thing is, that can't be just *any* file. RPM is looking for the *actual* `rpmsign` executable. You get the error `Permiso denegado` (permission denied) when RPM tries to *execute* that directory. (I'm assuming there's a missing line in your question, where you try to run `rpm --addsign` again`.)

So, what you need to do is first `rmdir /usr/bin/rpmsign`, because the directory you created will get in the way of installing the actual RPM. It happens that this is provided by the `rpm-sign` package. You can find that by running `dnf whatprovides /usr/bin/rpmsign` — or, you can actually just straight-up tell DNF (or Yum; doesn't matter) to install it:

```
$ sudo dnf install /usr/bin/rpmsign
Last metadata expiration check: 2:45:11 ago on Wed May  4 08:23:32 2016.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package         Arch          Version                     Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 rpm-sign        x86_64        4.13.0-0.rc1.13.fc23        updates         55 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 55 k
Installed size: 17 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
rpm-sign-4.13.0-0.rc1.13.fc23.x86_64.rpm        140 kB/s |  55 kB     00:00    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            44 kB/s |  55 kB     00:01     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Installing  : rpm-sign-4.13.0-0.rc1.13.fc23.x86_64                        1/1 
  Verifying   : rpm-sign-4.13.0-0.rc1.13.fc23.x86_64                        1/1 

Installed:
  rpm-sign.x86_64 4.13.0-0.rc1.13.fc23                                          

Complete!
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it happens that the machine had inode errors, as a result it had a serious hardware problem, I think incoherent errors should always be suspected. Another mistake was applying Fedora 21 as a server, due to the lack of design for that purpose. novice heifer times as adm, I think that in a functional computer that solution would be applied well. Greetings from Argentina